# Quantikz \ctrlbundle causing the document not to compile?

Tags: tikz-cd, undefined, quantikz

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{quantikz}
        \qwbundle[alternate]{} & \ctrlbundle{1} &  \gate{R}\qwbundle[alternate]{} \\
        \qw & \targ{} & \qw 
    \end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

When I do it on Overleaf everything works just fine, but when I do it on my local TeXstudio with xelatex and texlive 2020 I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. ^^I\end{quantikz}
You have requested package `', but the package provides `quantikz'.
```

What could be causing it? Any known solution?

Comment: Why do you use tikz-cd package (where)?

Comment: @Sebastiano: well this is just a small part of all the code I have, I'm using it elsewhere. Anyway even if I import tikz instead of tikz-cd I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: The `\ctrlbundle` command did not exist in earlier versions of `quantikz`. You can download the most recent version of the tikzlibrary from http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/quantikz/tikzlibraryquantikz.code.tex and place it in the same directory as your document to be able to compile the document.

Comment: @Marijn: Yes, thanks! Now it works. If you wanna add a reply I'll select it as the accepted ones in case this will be helpful to anyone in the future.

Comment: @Marijn I delete my answer. My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano: yeah unfortunately it didn't solve for me but thanks anyway for your time